# How to use eb's cli tool to update deployment policy to immutable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to update an existing environment to immutable updates to work around flaky deployments as described by [this (not my) blog post](https://jg.gg/2020/04/15/debugging-elastic-beanstalk/).

After reading [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html) - specifically the "The aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate namespace" section, it appears I should be able to add an `.ebextensions` folder at the same level as my `.elasticbeanstalk` folder, and put the following in an arbitrarily-named config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Immutable
```

and issue an `eb deploy`.

Having done this and receiving an "Environemnt update completed successfully" result, I went to check the aws console and this environment is still set to "Deployment policy: Rolling." An `eb config` shows `aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:RollingUpdateType` is set to "Health" (which doesn't make much sense but I guess that's a labeling issue so, whatever).

Will this just not work or am I doing something obviously stupid?

Pedantic Note - I'm aware I can do this by hand editing `eb config` and checking a box in the console, but I want to automate the change so we can apply it to other environments. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a little more.

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Immutable
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    DeploymentPolicy: Immutable
```

What you did enables immutable updates for configuration changes only. For  deployments you need the last two lines from the code above.

You can see more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentmgmt-updates-immutable.html) at `Example .ebextensions/immutable-all.config`.

Comment: I can't say whether this worked or not since we've since dropped our EB stack completely in favor of serverless, which required some rewrites, but we're happier to not be dealing with crazy EB issues constantly.